# Erase unknown string between two known strings in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex

Is it possible to take for example the string:

```
[abcdef]
```

And turn it into:

```
[]
```

Using Notepad++, considering I don't know that between the brackets is the string "abcdef"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is very possible. You can do this by making a regex search and replace.

Search for `(\[).+?(\])`
Replace with: `$1$2`

There are more examples, but your question specified brackets.

The reason for using `\[` and `\]` is because brackets themselves are regex parameters and thus have to be escaped.

Comment: I believe replace with can also be \1\2 or \\1\\2. Not sure which of the two it is, so I used $1$2 because I know that one works. Of course, replace with can also be [], but it probably has to be escaped too, so `\[\]`

Comment: @LPChip `\1\2` will work

Answer (score 2):

#### How can I change `[abcdef]` to `[]`?

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `\[.*\]`
- Set "Replace with" to `[]`
- Enable "Regular expression"

  [image]

---

#### Further reading

- [FAQ Desk: Where to find REGEX documentation ? | Notepad++ Community](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/15765/faq-desk-where-to-find-regex-documentation)
- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
- [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)
- [RegExper: Regular Expression Visualiser](https://regexper.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, ill give it a +1 but LPChip answered first :D

Comment: @Tom : If brackets inside brackets are a possibility in your use case, you could use .*? instead of just .* to make the match non-greedy, depending on your desired outcome.